# Django database not updating

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have the following function:

```
def automatch(game):
"""Automatically matches a game with another game in the database
that has the same wager. If no such game is found, the game is saved and
just waits around in the database."""

    other_game_exists = Game.objects.filter(wager=game.wager,
                                        matched_with=None).exclude(id=game.id).exists()
    if other_game_exists:
        other_game = Game.objects.filter(wager=game.wager,
                                    matched_with=None).exclude(id=game.id)[0]
        other_game = Game.objects.get(wager=game.wager,
                                    matched_with=None, id=other_game.id)
        game.matched_with = other_game
        other_game.matched_with = game
        game.save()
        other_game.save()
    else:
        game.save()
```

When I call this function, `game.matched_with` is `other_game`, as it should be; however, `other_game.matched_with` stays `None`. So, the database is not being updated with `other_game`'s new `matched_with` information. Why? The database is sqlite3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the `game` before you attach it to `other_game`.

```
game.matched_with = other_game
game.save()
other_game.matched_with = game
other_game.save()
```

This will then save `other_game` with the newly created instance of `game`.

Read more about [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) in the docs.

Comment: Actually, that's what I had originally, but it wasn't working (the exact same issue), so I changed it to this. I'm fairly sure it's something to do with `save()` but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Hmm odd, the first save should create a working instance that you can then attach to other objects. Out of curiosity does it work if you try: `other_game.matched_with = Game.objects.get(id=game.id)` ?

Comment: I figured out what the problem was! Automatch() works fine with your previous suggestion, the problem before was with my unit test. The database was indeed being updated; when I return `other_game` from the function and check its `matched_with` field I get `game`. In my test, I created a `game_1` and a `game_2` with same wager and I was automatching `game_1` and, stupidly enough, I was getting frustrated because `game_2`'s `matched_with` field wasn't updating. When I update `game_2` to be the `other_game` returned in `automatch` I get the right answer. Thanks for bearing with me!